# unable to run in server

Tags: ember.js

I have downloaded code from code project site (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511031/A-sample-real-time-web-application-using-Ember-js?msg=4693404#xx4693404xx) it is running fine when i run in local but once i keep in server and browse with url it is not opening.

http://drjeppesen.dyndns.org/onlineorder/ser/Ember.n.SignalR/

Displaying empty screen. Can anyone help to find the way how can i run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the browser console, your server is requesting the javascripts and css's in the wrong path. For example, a request is made for http://drjeppesen.dyndns.org/onlineorder/Scripts/u.js, but the correct path is http://drjeppesen.dyndns.org/onlineorder/ser/Ember.n.SignalR/Scripts/u.js

Comment: Hi Have fixed this issue and form is opening now but still i am haing 1 issue POST http://drjeppesen.dyndns.org/customer/create/ [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 293ms]      But i kept this controller folder at this url but unable to found fix this issue. Please help me